# how to access the element in a jQuery filter function?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
x=[{id:1}, {id:2}]
```

and I want to access the `id` of the element in a `filter` function :

```
x.filter(function(index) {
   if( x[index]['id'] == 1)
       return true;
   return false;
}
```

but is says `x[index] is undefined`

what should I do to access `x[index]` in `filter` function?

Comment: first argument is for the object itself in array,you should use the second argument. function(item,index,arr)

Comment: You seems to be using JavaScript's built in filter method, not jQuery. I recommend to read the documentation before you use an unfamiliar function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: And don't return true and false from an `if` statement. Directly return the result of the condition: `return foo == 1;`

Comment: try - `x = x.filter(function(element) {return element.id == 1;});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only pass one parameter, then that parameter points to item and not index. You need to use `index.id==1` instead of `x[index]['id'] == 1`:

```
x.filter(function(index) {
 if(index.id == 1)
   return true;
   return false;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xLzoarjv/)**

Answer (score 2):

You have to do like this:

```
x.filter(function(item,index) {

   if( item.id == 1)
       return true;
   return false;
});
```

The first parameter is item of array and second parameter is the index of array.

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/r1e4p1eo/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can add another argument for the current element.

```
x.filter(function(elmt, index){
 if( elmt['id'] == 1)
   return true;
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.filter` ([`Array.prototype.filter`][1]) calls the supplied function with 3 arguments:

```
function(element, index, array) {
    ...
```

- `element` is the particular array element for the call.
- `index` is the current index of the element
- `array` is the array being filtered.

You can use any or all of the arguments.

In your case, `i` refers to the `element` and is used in the body of your function:

```
function(i){
    return (i > 2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check with the below code

```
x = x.filter(function(item) {
   if( item.id == 1)
       return true;
   return false;
});
```